# The possibility of knowledge

Tags: epistemology, skepticism

If a skeptic comes to argue against the possibility of Knowledge, Would you refute it? If yes, why? If not, Why?

Comment: Skip straight to gorilla wrestling. You can't have a debate in English with somebody who insists (in English, expecting to be understood) that neither of you can possibly know how to speak English.

Comment: Ask him how does he KNOW it. Or any other thing. Remember him that knowledge is a model of the terrain, not the terrain itself. As such, the model (knowledge) is quite different to the terrain. Even if you have a bad model, it's still a model: bad knowledge is still possible, and it is still knowledge.

Comment: I don't believe in skepticism.

Comment: @gs I don't *know how* to speak English, I just do it. But I'm not much of a Chinese Room, I'd be terrible at that.

Comment: @gs there is the argument that even a little child can refute knowledge. I saw in the university some experiments where people trying to convince kids under 2 years old that open meant close and the other way around too and child refuted it with as they could... without actually mastering a language.

Comment: This seems to be more about solipsism to than skepticism. But also too broad a question for this site.

Comment: Eric is in Paris only if Kit is in Geneva. If Kit is in Geneva, I can drink Whiskey in Turkey. If I can drink Whiskey in Turkey, Mr. Morgan, the barber with a limp will shave Ms. Jenna. God bless.

Answer (score 2):

If a skeptic were to argue against the possibility of knowledge, I would first seek to understand their perspective and the specific reasons for their skepticism. Then, I would draw upon my knowledge base to provide relevant information and counterpoints that may be helpful in addressing their concerns.

Ultimately, the question of whether knowledge is possible is a complex and nuanced one that has been debated by philosophers and thinkers for centuries. While there may be no definitive answer to this question, engaging in thoughtful and respectful dialogue can help us better understand and appreciate the different perspectives that exist on this topic.

Comment: I guess if we can't decide that knowledge is possible, it shows that knowledge is not possible. I'm pretty sure that arithmetic and airplanes are possible.

Comment: A skeptic who argues against the possibility of Knowledge has no knowledge by his own argument.
Why acknowledge the skeptic at all?